# Spring Security/Spring Data Repository - how to secure all methods, depending on that the principal matches the user_id column?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-repositories

I have multiple Spring Data Repositories and a lot of my tables have the column user_id.

I have to secure my API so that each user is only allowed to see and change the data records belonging to him. Except for users with admin-role, which are allowed to change all data records.

My first intention was to create a custom implementation for each of the repositories and to override the save, delete, findAll etc. methods. Inside the custom implementation i can get the principal and do a manual check on the usergroup and user_id.

But this will lead to a lot of custom implementations and in case i forget to override a method (e.g. findAll, which would be horrible), this could create a big security problem.

Is there any better way to achieve this? I think this should be a common security case and it feels like i havn't found the best solution yet.

E.g. i have this database table:

```
CREATE TABLE sell_order(
     id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
     user_id varchar(255),
     FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_data (user_id)
);
```

And this Spring Data Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "sellorders", path = "sellorders")
public interface SellOrderRepository extends CrudRepository<SellOrder, Long> {

    @RestResource(path = "findByUserId", rel = "findByUserId")
    @Query(value = "SELECT s FROM SellOrder s WHERE s.userId = :userId")
    SellOrder findByUserId(@Param("userId") String userId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement the same feature in my project, I create the following you method for authentication:

```java
     private boolean isSameAuthor(long uid) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println((UserPrincipal)authentication.getPrincipal());
        UserPrincipal author =  (UserPrincipal)authentication.getPrincipal();
        return author.getUid() == uid;
    }

    private boolean isAdmin() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return authentication.getAuthorities().stream().map(role -> role.getAuthority()).collect(Collectors.toSet()).contains("ROLE_ADMIN");
    }
```

Here In your case you should pass `user_id`. You can use something like this.